# String Causing Unexpected Errors

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with some code, in the constructor of the level, i have this.public

```
Level(int width, int height, String level) {
    grid=new Block[width][height];
    String v = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            char s = level.charAt(y * height + x);
            if (s=='#') {
                grid[x][y] = new Wall(x, y);
            } else if (s=='_'){
                grid[x][y] = new Block(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only when I run the Level initializer with the following...

```
              new Level(16,16,"###############" +
                              "#_____________#" +
                              "#___######____#" +
                              "#___#____###__#" +
                              "#___#__###_#__#" +
                              "#####_________#" +
                              "#_____#__######" +
                              "#___###_______#" +
                              "#_#_#_# #####_#" +
                              "#_#___#____#__#" +
                              "#_#####__###_##" +
                              "#_____####____#" +
                              "#_#_#______##_#" +
                              "###_#__#####__#" +
                              "#___#______#__#" +
                              "###############");
```

I get

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
    String Index out of range: 240
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at Level.<init>(Level.java:17)
at Game.<init>(Game.java:12)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your grid is 16 * 15 (and hence the exception while calculating `char` position)

**[EDIT]** modify you formula

```
char s = level.charAt(y * width + x);
```

Comment: Ah my bad. Thanks so much for catching that.

Comment: yep
also to be on safer side I will always pass height as first arg and then width to my func....

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
char s = level.charAt(y * height + x);
```

should probably be

```
char s = level.charAt(y * width + x);
```